# Proper XPath Syntax

Tags: php, xpath, domcrawler

I'm trying to access an attribute of a previous sibling, but it's proving difficult.

So basically the web page I'm trying to scrape is TERRIBLE and the anchor tags use crappy onclick instead of href. Stupid, I know. I'm trying to first find the anchor tag containing an onclick with the `window.open('servletLinkJunkHere...')`, then move to the previous sibling, which is an `img` tag, and extract the `src` attribute from it.

```
<IMG SRC="images/warning.gif" ALT="blah blah blah" STYLE="position:relative;top:2px;cursor:help;">
<a href="#" onclick="javascript:window.open('servletLinkJunkHere...')>
```

And here's the xpath I'm trying to use:

```
$url_pre = 'a[onclick*="'servletLinkJunkHere...'"]/preceding-sibling::img/@src';
```

Any ideas on how I can accomplish this? I know it's possible, I'm just not totally proficient in xpath queries. Also, are there any good resources for learning all the nooks and crannies of xpath? Thanks!

EDIT: So this is what I have but it doesn't seem to be returning anything but an empty array.

```
$url_email = "EditNotificationInfoServlet?cb=on&id=" . $id . "&sessionId=1";

$url_pre = "a[contains(@onclick,'" . $url_email . "')]/preceding-sibling::IMG/@SRC";

$final_text = $crawler->filterXPath($url_pre)->each(function($crawler, $i) {
        return $crawler->text();
});
```

Comment: What is the context for `$crawler`? You may need to prefix the XPath expression with `//`

Comment: This is a function, and I pass it a `$crawler` object. I have many other functions, and they work just fine, so the context should be fine.

Comment: Sorry, I meant the document context. Unless the document context for `$crawler->filterXPath` is the immediate parent of your HTML `<a>` element, you won't find it. Using `//a[contains(...` will search the entire document from whatever context it has

Comment: Hmm, I tried `//a[contains...` as well, and it didn't seem to provide a working solution. Continuing to research.

Comment: Maybe just try `//a/preceding-sibling::img` or even `//a` and see what you get back

Comment: Can't do that, because there are many, many `a` tags throughout the document, I have to find the one that contains a certain string (that is in the onclick), then go to the preceding sibling. (Note: it doesn't seem to be entering the `each(function($crawler, ...` function at all, I tried putting an echo in.

Comment: I realise that, I was just suggesting you start simple and work up from there. Make sure you can even find any image preceding an anchor, etc

Comment: I printed off my combined string and I get `&sessionId=1&displayMode=update¬ificationType=1&` and as you can see, there's some weird symbol. It's suppose to be `update&notification`. I think that might be the problem.

Comment: I'd say so. FYI, assuming you're using Symfony's DOMCrawler, it should work fine given the correct values to search for ~ https://eval.in/320191

Comment: Yes, Symfony's DOMCrawler. So then do you think it is that weird character messing stuff up? `¬` character?

Comment: Definitely. I can't see that in your code though so you must be omitting something (the string in your question code ends at `sessionId=1`).

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to use the following xpath:

```
a[contains(@onclick,'servletLinkJunkHere...')]/preceding-sibling::IMG/@SRC
```

Comment: I tried your code, no luck. Perhaps I did it wrong. I edited my original question and posted the exact code I have, if maybe that could help fine tune what my mistake is.